# Multilevel data with correlation within subjects

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, binary-data, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset with 1206 deputies from two different chambers (1998 and 2002, respectively). In addition, there are 18 parties, and some deputies are in both chambers (the ones who were reelected). I am interested in the relation between party discipline (in a scale from 0 to 100) and the probability of geting appointed as party leader (0 or 1), but I am also interested in separate estimates for each party.

A classmate told me that the following mixed effect model would be appropriate, but I don't know what to do with the correlation within subjects:

```
model <- glmer(leader ~ discipline + (1 + discipline|chamber:party), 
               data, family=binomial)
```

What is the structure of these data and which model would be appropriate in this case (using R)?

Comment: Gelman and Hill (2007) say that there is nothing wrong with having groups with few individuals (even when there is only one). But I am not sure whether I can add an intercept for the deputies or not.